# Wiring ceiling fan 3 black and 3 white wires no ground

Tags: ceiling, fans

Taking a light fixture down and installing ceiling fan in bedroom. House was built in 1968[image]
How to wire ceiling fan to this?

Wires coming from ceiling fan are Blue,Black,White,Green.

Comment: What's your question? Have you already pulled everything apart or is the current wiring arrangement still intact?

Comment: Hopefully you took pictures of how the wires were connected.  Most likely you have power coming in(one black and white) power going some place else and a switch loop.

Comment: The fixture is still up, I haven't unwired anything yet, but I do have pics but wouldn't ler me upload them.

Comment: I check the wiring on the switch and only has a white and black wire going to it.

Comment: That is a switch loop.  You will find at the fixture one white wire connected  probably to two blacks.  It is important you mark the two blacks and white wire, to connect them back together after.  If you are lucky the white will already have a black mark on it.

Comment: Welcome to HI. As far ss i know you can upload an image, it just isnt embedded, which someone else will do for you. Its also helpful to add extra info by editing your post.

Comment: That's exactly how it is. I've got 2 black wires and 1 white wire caped of together, and 1 black wire caped with black on light fixture, and the other 2 white wires are connected to the white wire on fixture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an old-style switch loop:

- Black wire nut = Two blacks/white = incoming hot (black), outgoing hot (black), always hot to switch (white)
- Yellow wire nut = switched hot + light hot
- Red wire nut = incoming neutral + outgoing neutral + light neutral

This is a standard configuration. For a new light or light/fan, connect black (hot) to the yellow wire nut and white (neutral) to the red wire nut. But there are two limitations:

- No neutral in the switch box

This limits your ability to use a smart switch. However, many fans now come with, or have available as an optional accessory, a remote control. The remote control receiver is installed in the ceiling on the fan and allows control of both fan and light, so unless you need a timer, motion sensor or WiFi control you should be OK.

- Only one switched hot

Traditionally, a fan/light has two separate switched hots, one for the fan and one for the light. You only have one switched hot. The typical fan/light remote is the usual solution, or you can get a fan with pull chains.

Comment: Will OP need to change that normal light box to one made for a fan?

Comment: I do have to switch out the box with a metal box, which I have, will swap out boxes when I install ceiling fan